# sdk location not found in react native

Tags: sdk, react-native

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at '/home/ranaji/myapp/android/local.properties'.

need permanent solution. pls ans me if anyone know

thanks for help

Comment: Have you android studio??

Answer (score 0):

Go to the *android/* directory of your react-native project

Create a file called *local.properties* with this line:

> sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk